# How to add fade transitions to entities in Aframe

Tags: animation, fade, aframe, transition

I would like to fade an entity in A-Frame and I can't seem to find a solution using the documentation. Any help would be appreciated
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

For a-frame 0.9.0+ check out Kevins anwser. `<a-animation>` is deprecated since then.

---

You could use `<a-animation>` changing the `material.opacity` attribute like this:

```
<a-entity id="myEntity">
  <a-animation attribute="material.opacity" dur="1000" repeat="0></a-animation>
</a-entity>
```

. You can check out the documentation [here](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/core/animations.html#sidebar).

Live fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5wwraxcs/3/).

Comment: I recommend the animation component. I am going to deprecate that.

Comment: @ngokevin thx for the information gotta get familiar with your component and anime.js :) You want to completely remove `<a-animation>` in favor of your component ?

Answer (score 2):

Include animaton component: https://github.com/ngokevin/kframe/tree/master/components/animation

Then:

```
<a-box animation="property: components.material.material.opacity; from: 1; to: 0"></a-box>
```

I go through `components` for performant tweening that skips A-Frame setAttribute.